# Creating a Calculator with R

Tags: r

I am actually new here. I would like to create a simple calculator in R Programming with combination of readline() function and different functions
Here is my current code:

```
add <- function(x, y) {
  return(x + y)
}
subtract <- function(x, y) {
  return(x - y)
}
multiply <- function(x, y) {
  return(x * y)
}
divide <- function(x, y) {
  return(x / y)
}
factors <- function(x) {
  if(choice <=5){
  choice <- readline(prompt="Enter the number: ")
  print(paste("The factors of",x,"are:"))
  for(i in 1:x) {
    if((x %% i) == 0) {
      print(i)
    }
  }}
}
print("******Simple R Calculator - Select operation:")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")
print("5.Factors")
print("6.Prime")
choice = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter choice[1/2/3/4/5/6]: "))
num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter first number: "))
num2 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter second number: "))
operator <- switch(choice,"+","-","*","/")
result <- switch(choice, add(num1, num2), subtract(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2), divide(num1, num2), factors(i))
print(paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result))
```

When I run this function, it asks to enter the first number and second number to get the results. But for "choice" number 5 and 6, I do not want to have first number and second number popped up instead only requires one number.
Please help me guys and clarify if I may not quite clear on my question. 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: please reformat your code syntax to a readable format

Comment: You can format your code by highlighting it and clicking the button at the top of the box where you ask your question or by pressing Ctrl + K.

Comment: I am still having difficulties to reformat my code. could you guys please refer to the link for the image?

Comment: @Nelson The link is even worse,  we cannot cut and paste from an image. No one wants to type it all in.

Comment: Sure guys,I will try to reformat my code syntax to a readable format and post it very soon

Comment: Hi Guys, I hope that is the format you expect. Cheers

Comment: You know how to use `if` clauses, so what is the question?

Comment: I think I got stuck with If clauses as I am new to R Programming. I kind of use If clause in the function but it doesn't actually work.

Comment: @Frank My question is how can I avoid getting to enter the first number and second number instead getting to enter only one number when I choose number 5 to find factors of number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a basic if statement is what you are looking for. If I am understanding the question right, if choice is 5 or 6 you don't want to prompt for 2 numbers. Try this:

```
if (choice == 5 | choice == 6) {
  num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter number: "))
} else {
  num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter first number: "))
  num2 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter second number: "))
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for this. You made my day.

Comment: No problem, if you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: Done :). Thanks again mate.